# Checkbox onchange submit form GET

Tags: jquery, get, forms

I have a checkbox on a page. I would like that checkbox to submit to the server with it's value, for example: `/PageName?cb=true` or `/PageName?cb=1`, but for some reason, it just goes to `/PageName?`. What am I doing wrong here?

Form:

```
<form action="/PageName" id="cbForm" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb">
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#cb").change(
            function () {
                $("#cbForm").submit();
            }
        )
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">
```

Should contain the "name" attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="cb">
```

The name attribute is used to denote the request parameter to send. And you still need the id to use the input in jQuery.

Comment: Fail, dunno how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You missing Name Attribute**

> You also can do with **onchange**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="/PageName" id="cbForm" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="cb" onchange='$("#cbForm").submit();'>
</form>
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

try like this , i searched every i could find anything near to your query so i tried in a different way like this .changing the action when form submits.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#cb").change(
            function () {
                 var n=$("#cbForm").attr('action');
                 var cb=$("#cb").val();
                 $("#cbForm").attr('action',n+'?cb='+cb)
                $("#cbForm").submit();
                alert($("#cbForm").attr('action'));
            }
        )
    });
</script>

<form action="/PageName" id="cbForm" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb" name=cb value=1>
</form>
```